a function to reload, refresh or update the div content (part of page, not whole page) when buttom clicked using javascript ajax without jquery?
this code is in function.php
<?php
# get company function
function get_company($db)
{
    $company_id = $_GET['id'];
    $company = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company_id = :company_id");
    $company->execute(['company_id' => $company_id]);
    $company = $company->fetch();
    return $company;
}
?>

this code is in index.php (the main file or home page)
<?php
$companies = get_companies($db);
?>
<article id="article">
            <?php if ($companies->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
                <!-- list of all companies -->
                <?php 
                foreach ($companies as $company) {
                ?>
                    <a class="i" href="2.php?id=<?= $company['company_id'] ?>">
                        <div class="h">
                            <img src="images/<?= $company['company_image'] ?>">
                        </div>
                        <h2><?= $company['company_name'] ?></h2>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="n">empty</div>
            <?php }  ?>
</article>

<button id="button1" onclick="m(this.id)">click me to reload articles</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="m(this.id)">click me to reload articles</button>
<button id="button3" onclick="m(this.id)">click me to reload articles</button>

this code is in js file
<script>
function article(id) {
  url = new URL(window.location.href);
  url.searchParams.set("group_id", id);
  window.history.pushState("", "", url);

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("article")...//write some code here to refresh or reload article element when you click button.
    }
  };
  url.search;
  xhttp.open("GET", "php/function.php"+url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

I don't know how can I reload, refresh or update the div content (part of page, not whole page) when buttom clicked using javascript ajax.
I need a function to get url content and reload the article div (not whole page, part of a page) something like ajax using javascript but not jquery or other libraries.

I like to use DomParser.parseFromString() to turn the returned string content into html which can then be inserted into the desired location in the DOM.  By the way, highly recommend Javascript's fetch API with async/await over XMLHttpRequest.

"php/function.php"+url doesn't look right. It should be "php/function.php?id=" + id

Is onclick="m(this.id)" supposed to be onclick="article(this.id)"?

Are you company IDs really the same as the button IDs?

To reload just the DIV, use document.getElementById("article").innerHTML = whatever you want to show;

...and that has nothing directly to do with ajax, you can do that anytime. (But of course in your case you want to replace the content with data which was downloaded from the ajax request, although in fact the data could come from anywhere in theory)
